# Xamarin ZXing.Net.Forms plugin displays a white background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, plugins, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I guys I hope you guys are doing great. I have a problem with the **ZXing.Net.Forms** plugin on Xamarin forms when it loads it shows a white background and at some time the white background clears. Kindly help on how could I fix the issue.

I have requested and asked for the camera permission but the issue still persists.

This is the page where I created the scanner view.

```
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MyScanPage : ContentPage
{
    private ZXingScannerView zxing;
    private ZXingDefaultOverlay overlay;
    public EventHandler isRefresh;
    public MyScanPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
        try
        {
            zxing = new ZXingScannerView
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
            };

            zxing.OnScanResult += (result) =>
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    zxing.IsAnalyzing = false;
                    Common.scanCheckOutCode = result.Text;
                    Navigation.PopAsync();
                    isRefresh(result.Text, EventArgs.Empty);
                });

            overlay = new ZXingDefaultOverlay
            {
                TopText = "Hold your phone up to the barcode",
                BottomText = "Scanning will happen automatically",
                ShowFlashButton = zxing.HasTorch,
            };
            overlay.FlashButtonClicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                zxing.IsTorchOn = !zxing.IsTorchOn;
            };
            var grid = new Grid
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                RowDefinitions =  {new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star) } },
            };
            grid.Children.Add(zxing);
            grid.Children.Add(overlay);

            Content = grid;
     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            Common.ErrorMessage("CheckOutScanPage/Constructor: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        zxing.IsScanning = true;
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        zxing.IsScanning = false;
        base.OnDisappearing();
        GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
    }
}
```

Comment: If no one comes along today with a solution, I suggest adding this as an issue at [ZXing.Net.Mobile - issues](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues). If you do, please add a link here to the issue you create. And in that issue, add a link to this StackOverflow question.

Comment: Does setting the `BackgroundColor` to `Transparent` work? It could be that the default `BackgroundColor` is white?

Comment: Try Horizontal & vertical options to CenterAndExpand or try giving fixed height & width to scanner view. Just a random guess as I also used to face the same issue.